# Marscapone vs cream cheese- lessen sugar?

Tags: substitutions

I am making cheese danish and love marscapone. Do I lessen the sugar because of marscapone’s sweeter taste? Is added salt necessary- or flour for sturdiness as suggested in another article? Thanks!!!

Comment: I see a few additional issues that you might need to consider, particularly the consistency - mascarpone will melt in the oven, whereas cream cheese is a lot more stable.